# how to pass both session and Request.URL in unit test c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a controller which requires both Session state object and also Url Helper to be mocked from unit test and in this regard i have created the following below code

```
   [TestMethod]
         public void PaymentControllerTest_CallPaymentProvider()
         {

             var controller = new PaymentController();
             //  var model = new Dictionary<string, string>();
             var mockDatabaseWrapper = new MockDatabaseWrapper();
             DatabaseWrapper.SetDatabaseWrapper(mockDatabaseWrapper);


             var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
             request.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(
              new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection {
             {"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"} });

             request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost"));
             var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
             context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);


             controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), controller);

             controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(controller.HttpContext, new RouteData()), new RouteCollection());
             RouteCollection routes = new System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection();



             var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
             var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
             mockSession.SetupGet(Session => Session["CurrentCulture"]).Returns(1); //somevalue
             mockControllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);

             var result = controller.CallPaymentProvider(123) as ViewResult; 
         }
```

Now the problem is that when i create the controller context i am able to pass only one. can any of the experts help how to pass both session and url in controller context.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why?  You should easily be able to, although I'm not sure what all happens within UrlHelper, and that might be worth investigating?  Anyway, what happens with this test, it fails, and if so, where?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass both the url and session to the controller context as if you see the above code controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), controller); and for session again i need to declare controller.ControllerContext=mockControllerContext.object it is able to take only session. So basically i am not able to pass both url and session and so my test fails or in other sense i am not able to pass both values to my paymentcontroller.